# Visual Studio 2010 not recognizing .NET framework 4.0.3

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to open a solution I'm getting this message

> The C# project "X" is targeting ".NETFramework, Version=v4.03", which is not installed on this machine

I installed the upgrade from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29053) but that didn't fix the problem. I restarted the machine just in case but no luck

Does anyone know what's missed?

Comment: I think I've tried everything under the sun to recreate this, and no luck. I'm pretty sure I don't have 4.0.3 installed either. Can you just target 4.0, which should run the latest patch version?

Comment: @StevenV: thanks for your answer. I was able to resolve it, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is resolved,
I needed to install [Multi-Targeting Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.3 (KB2600213)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29052))

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the .NET Framework 4.0 SDK, which can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

What you installed is the .NET 4.0 runtime, required for running .NET 4.0 applications as a client.

Comment: +1 This wasn't exaclty the answer but pointed me in the correct direction that I might had to install something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try confirming what versions you have installed on your machine, i.e. go to

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

or the following on a 64bit machine:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64

do the underlying folders here in include v4.0.30319 (or similar)?

Now what does the VS project contain as its target framework:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```